# Linking two differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

The solution and plot of the Differential equation is $\frac{d^2S(r)}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dS(r)}{dr}-S(r)+3S^3(r)=0$

```
S0 = S[r] /. 
   NDSolve[{S''[r] + 1/r S'[r] - S[r] + S[r]^3 == 0, 
     S[1/10000000000000000] == 2.20620086, 
     S'[1/10000000000000000] == 0}, S, {r, 1/1000, 15}];
Plot[{S0}, {r, 1/100, 14}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

I have to use the above info in the differential equation:

$\frac{d^2Z(r)}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dZ(r)}{dr}-Z(r)+3S^2Z(r)-S^5(r)=0$

**And I have plotted like this: but it is not working**

```
sol = NDSolve[{s''[r] + 1/r s'[r] - s[r] + s[r]^3 == 0, 
    s[1/10000000000000000] == 2.20620086, 
    s'[1/10000000000000000] == 0}, s, {r, 1/1000, 15}];
sol = s[r] /. sol;
Z0 = Z[r] /. 
   NDSolve[{Z''[r] + 1/r*Z'[r] - Z[r] + 3 sol^2*Z[r] - sol^5 == 0, 
     Z[1/10000000000000000] == -16.17403, 
     Z'[1/10000000000000000] == 0}, Z, {r, 1/1000, 15}];
Plot[{Z0}, {r, 1/100, 14}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The output curve will be like: [image].

I have used r instead
 of $\rho$. I have tried several times to get the output  but it shows some following which I don't understand. I have looked the error to get but couldn't.

Sorry for the poor question. I have studied but couldn't fix it.

Comment: Hats off to you for this persistent tsunami of gibberish questions! When it comes to learn from others answer and comments about your post you show no positive effort whatsoever...Waiting for the light of resurrection here...

Answer (score 3):

Your coupled differential equations has nothing to do with linking. The appropriate word should be "coupled" not "linking", which can be solved very easily some thing like this

```
sol = NDSolve[{s''[r] + 1/r s'[r] - s[r] + 3 s[r]^3 == 0,Z''[r] + 1/r Z'[r] - Z[r] + 3 
s[r]^2 Z[r] - s[r]^5 == 0, s[1/10000000000000000] == 2.20620086, s'[1/10000000000000000] == 0
,Z[1/10000000000000000] == -16.17403, Z'[1/10000000000000000] == 0}, {s, Z}, {r, 1/1000, 15}]
```

Now for plotting we can use

```
Plot[{s[r] /. sol, Z[r] /. sol}, {r, 1/1000, 15}, PlotRange -> All, 

PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"s[r]", "Z[r]"}, Above]]
```

The output is

[image]

which clearly satisfy your condition on s and z.